# Cookbook on Odisha cuisine

Tags: indian-cuisine, cookbook

Do there exist cookbooks, possibly in English, about food from the state of Odisha, India -- preferably written by an author from that region?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cookbook request

Comment: This feels like it's probably okay in the same way sourcing questions are - the actual question is how to search for them, as evidenced by the answer suggesting searching for Orissa or Oriya instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any such cookbooks, but a google search turned up a lot of blogs with recipes. If you search, include Orissa and Oriya as well as Odisha.

I also found several English-language cookbooks through searching on Amazon.in (best search term was oriya cooking). Some of them are also available on their other sites. I have not seen or cooked from any of these cookbooks to give any personal recommendation.

[Purba: Feasts from the East: Oriya Cuisine from Eastern India](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0595267491)

[Classic Cooking of Orissa](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0044PY2K6)

[Healthy Oriya Cuisine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8129111187)

Comment: I just realized you are German; the first and third of those books seem to be available at amazon.de also.